# Quick way to enable/disable step filters in IntellliJ

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

In Eclipse it is possible to quick enable/disable step filters:

[image]

Is the same possible in IntelliJ?

UPDATE:
Related discussion with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153784

Answer (score 1):

In IDEA you can temporarily disable stepping filters using force step into (and smart step into)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would choose whether to step into certain packages/classes in IntelliJ IDEA:

1. open the Settings dialog: Ctrl-Alt-S,
2. type "stepping" into the filter field, and
3. toggle the "Do not step into the classes" check box.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot IntelliJ IDEA Settings dialog]

I am not aware of a keyboard shortcut or quicker alternative. Since I rarely want to step into the packages/classes that are in this list, this way is completely acceptable for me. I can understand that if you do want to toggle frequently, the "Use Step Filters" check box and the Shift-F5 keyboard shortcut in Eclipse are great (see [Eclipse Use Step Filters documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm&cp=1_4_7_2_20)).